# jquery enter key replace default click action

Tags: jquery, html

is there any way I can trigger a customized action, instead of default click action, when a link has been ENTER?

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkww24yg/)

HTML

```
<a href="#section2">Test Link</a>
<div id="section2">section 2</div>
```

JS

```
$('#section2').keypress(function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if(key == 13)  
    {
        // customised action
        return false;  
    }
})
```

In this example I wanna get rid of the section jump

Comment: Use `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the default action of the clicked element.

Comment: Actually I tried. http://jsfiddle.net/pkww24yg/1/ But it's still jumping.

Comment: please check your fiddle it has a mistake you are not trying to manipulate the click event for a but for div #section2 one more thing you did not load jquery please check http://jsfiddle.net/pkww24yg/3/ and its working as desired.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent any action that would go on an element, and replace it with your own, use preventDefault:

```
.keypress(function (e) {
    if(e.which === 13)  
    {
        e.preventDefault() // this will stop link/button execution.
        // do some actions
        return false;  
    }
})
```

Ref: 
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Remembar that keypress works on inputs, places where you can input something:) So on any input field inside your section2 block, enter press will trigger something.

Comment: Your fiddle is missing:
 - jQuery lib
 - input element, on witch you want to trigger enter press key.